How to plot poliastro Orbits in 3D? (OrbitPlotter3D() in VS Code python through Anaconda does not show the figure)
I'm trying to visualize intersections of poliastro Orbit objects in 3D using OrbitPlotter3D(). Despite following the documentation, the plot isn't displaying. Here's the relevant code:
# Plotting of orbits    
def plot_orbits(initial_orbit, final_orbit):
    frame = OrbitPlotter3D()
    frame.set_attractor(Earth)
    frame.plot(initial_orbit, label="Initial Orbit")
    frame.plot(final_orbit, label="Final Orbit")
    frame.show()

I've installed poliastro and plotly, and imported necessary modules:
from astropy import units as u
from poliastro.constants import J2000
from poliastro.bodies import Earth
from poliastro.plotting import OrbitPlotter3D
from poliastro.twobody import Orbit
import plotly.io as pio

I set the renderer to "browser" but also tried others without success.
# Setup plotting
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

I read on poliastro's GitHub that users in Spyder through Anaconda faced similar issues, resolved partially with StaticOrbitPlotter() for 2D cases. However, I need 3D visualization for orbit intersections.
Has anyone encountered and solved this challenge? I'd appreciate any ideas or alternative methods to visualize poliastro Orbits in 3D without coordinate transformations.
Thanks in advance!
